# Detect fieldset on mouse click JQUERY

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to add a single condition to the following Javascript that will stop the IF statement below eveluating to TRUE when user clicks inside a fieldset on the page.

I have tried allsorts but i'm guessing, I just tried adding "
&& !(e.target.isFieldSet))" but no joy. I've tried searching the web, anyone any ideas?

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').live('click', function(e) {

        //if not clicking an anchor tag or imag then assume user wants to go to details page
        if ((!$(e.target).is('a')) && (!$(e.target).is('img')) && (!$(e.target).is('th')) && !(e.target.isTextEdit)) {
            window.location = $("#AbsolutePath").val() + 'Waste.mvc/Details/' + $(this).attr('rowid');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: could we please see the html maybe you could make fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for: `!$(e.target).is('fieldset')`:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').live('click', function(e) {

        //if not clicking an anchor tag or imag then assume user wants to go to details page
        if ((!$(e.target).is('a')) && (!$(e.target).is('img')) && (!$(e.target).is('th')) && 
           !(e.target.isTextEdit) && !$(e.target).is('fieldset')) {
            window.location = $("#AbsolutePath").val() + 'Waste.mvc/Details/' + $(this).attr('rowid');
        }

    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zbdRT/

---

However, I would argue that this is unmaintainable code. What if you need to add more tags (as you're doing right now). Something like this would be better:

```
if (!$(e.target).is("a, img, th, fieldset") && !e.target.isTextEdit)
```

or, you could store tags you want to ignore in an array that you can add to easily (this also makes the code a bit more expressive as to your intentions):

```
var excluded = ["a", "img", "th", "fieldset" ];

if (!$(e.target).is(excluded.join(", ")) && !e.target.isTextEdit)
```